# onPause() invoked after camera.takePicture() in xperia Z2 - 5.1.1 and app crashing

Tags: android, image, callback, android-camera, surfaceview

I am developing an app which uses custom camera and it is working fine on most of the devices I tested.

But in Sony xperia z2(5.1.1) and z ultra (5.1.1 ) after `camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);` is executed the flow goes to shutterCallback , rawCallback and then onPause() gets invoked and app crashes.

Please help debug this problem.
Below is my code.

ButtonClickListener

```
clickButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(GlobalMembers.TAG,"shutter clicked");
                //v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.shutter_click));
                if(!cameraClicked){  
                    cameraClicked=true;
                    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);    
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.v(GlobalMembers.TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.v(GlobalMembers.TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
          }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try{
                Log.v(GlobalMembers.TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");                   
                cameraClicked=false;
                refreshPreview();                   
                if(data!=null){
                    byte[] rotatedData=rotateImageBeforeSaving(data);
                    setThumbView(rotatedData);
                    new SaveImageTask().execute(rotatedData);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(GlobalMembers.TAG," Error Occured onPictureCallBack ");
                resetCam();
            }
        }
    };
```

OnPause() method

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.v(GlobalMembers.TAG,"onPause Called");
        //thumbView.setTag("Loading");
        if(camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.lock();
            preview.setCamera(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Log on Sony Xperia

```
onPictureTaken - raw   
01-17 11:43:36.448 1350-1350/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro V/SMARTSELFIEPRO: onPause Called
01-17 11:43:42.238 1350-1350/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro V/SMARTSELFIEPRO: Inside setCamera
01-17 11:43:42.239 1350-1383/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro W/CameraBase: Camera service died!
```

Log on Lg G3

```
onPictureTaken - raw   
01-17 11:42:30.483 972-972/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro V/SMARTSELFIEPRO: onPictureTaken - jpeg   
01-17 11:42:30.605 972-972/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro D/SMARTSELFIEPRO: Width : 1920 Height : 1080
01-17 11:42:30.606 972-972/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro D/SMARTSELFIEPRO: calculateRotationBeforeSaving based on Orientation Sensor : 0
01-17 11:42:31.857 972-972/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro V/SMARTSELFIEPRO: inside setThumbView with data
01-17 11:42:31.857 972-972/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro D/SMARTSELFIEPRO: setThumbView(byte), width of thumbView= 240
01-17 11:42:31.969 972-2381/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro D/SMARTSELFIEPRO: ImageFilePath /storage/emulated/0/smartselfiepro/selfie_1453011151969.jpg
01-17 11:42:31.995 972-2381/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro D/SMARTSELFIEPRO: onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: 1 to /storage/emulated/0/smartselfiepro/selfie_1453011151969.jpg
01-17 11:42:31.995 972-2381/com.hybrid.probuk.selfiePro V/SMARTSELFIEPRO: inside refreshGallery
```